# Run various macros when clicking on different cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I came across VBA code that triggers a macro in Excel when clicking on a specific cell.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
            Call MyMacro
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm trying to add three scenarios.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
            Call MyMacro1
        End If
    End If
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10")) Is Nothing Then
            Call MyMacro2
        End If
    End If
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G23")) Is Nothing Then
            Call MyMacro3
        End If
    End If
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J33")) Is Nothing Then
            Call MyMacro4
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect macros to run when the cells noted in the code were clicked on.

Comment: Code looks okay to me. Are the cells all in the same sheet? Not click on cells in another sheet?

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort? Do you know how to set breakpoints and how to step through the code line by line? That would help you a lot.

Comment: First, did you put the above code into the right Worksheet module in VBA?  Second, this code is making me crazy.  This event is called after the worksheet is Activated and the Selection is changed.  The Selection range and the target range are the same range and they are in the ActiveSheet.  So just `If Target.Count=1 AND Target.Address="$D$4" Then call mymacro1`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using `Select Case` might be easier to manage.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
        Case "D4": MyMacro1
        Case "E10": MyMacro2
        Case "G23": MyMacro3
        Case "J33": MyMacro4
    End Select
End Sub
```